# undefined reference to sqrt(geany)

Tags: c, gcc, geany, sqrt

I use Geany for C programming. When I try to build the file it gives me

```
error:undefined reference to sqrt.
```

Compile: `gcc -Wall -c "%f"`

Build: `gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f"`

Execute: `./%e`

I tried to add `-lm` to the build command but then it gives me

```
gcc error:no such file or directory.Compilation Failed.
```

Comment: `#include <math.h>`. Place this on top of ur code.

Comment: Please show addition of `-lm` in your build command.

Comment: @ForceBru I've already done that.

Comment: @Dayal rai gcc -Wall -olm "%e" "%f"

Comment: @MarvinMicek, then find this file's location and add this to the compiler invocation: `-I /path/where/this/file/is`

Comment: The compiler does not show any errors.

Comment: `-olm` says `lm` is the name of the output file, not to link against libm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler and linker options with arguments must be separate, you can't compile them like you do.

Make them separate, like e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lm
```

Comment: @MarvinMicek The option `-l` (small letter L) tells the linker to link with a library, in this case a library called `m` which is the math library.

Comment: In a case where math.h is not included,will this affect the compilation?Because now my `Build Command` is `gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lm.`

Comment: @MarvinMicek The header file `<math.h>` includes the *declarations* of the math library functions, without them the compiler will not know these functions exist.

Comment: Shouldn't this be enabled by default?

Comment: @MarvinMicek Do you mean the inclusion of `<math.h>`? Or the linking of the math library? It's because of historical reasons that the math functions are in a separate library, because handling of floating point values used to be very complex and CPU intensive, as well as taking space which was at a premium back when C was created.

Comment: I meant the linking of the math library.